# Как скрыть тулбары на айфоне в сафари при смене ориентации на пейзажную?

Tags: javascript, css, ios, iphone, safari

Пробовал следующее:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimal-ui">
```

и

```
window.addEventListener('load', 
    function() {
        setTimeout(scrollTo, 0, 0, 1);
    },
    false);
```

Это не сработало. Можете посоветовать какие-нибудь еще способы?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно [такое](http://gajus.com/sandbox/brim/demo/) поведение?

[github](https://github.com/gajus/brim) взят [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26884561)

Я бы рекомендовал всю ветку оттуда почитать. Познавательно

Comment: Взял их демку, посмотрел - то, что нужно. Но, добавляю в brin-main больше текста, получаю следующее: при вертикальной ориентации скролл перестает работать (когда показывается brin-mask), соответственно brin-mask не убирается. Горизонтально все ок, скроллится, тулбаров нет.

Comment: к сожалению дальше я не помогу