# Скрытие строки адреса в мобильном браузере

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как на мобильной версии сайта сделать, чтобы при прокрутке вниз пряталась строка адреса, а при прокрутке обратно появлялась?

Comment: 1. Никак. Все от браузера зависит 2. Вот такая штука есть http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453112/176892

Comment: Да, это наверное дефолтный функционал браузера. У меня тогда другой вопрос. Из-за чего он может не скролиться.